# How to create a class with annonymous functions in Angular8

Tags: angular, anonymous-function, anonymous-class

I'm developing an Angular 8 app and need to use a library for displaying 3D models (JS + WASM). For interaction between my Tree Table and 3D model, I need to register an observer in this library.

The given codesample for registering the observer (for this library) is written in AngularJS:

**Registration:**

```
$scope.RegisterSelectionObserver = function() {
    if ($scope.selectionObserver == null) {
        $scope.selectionObserver = new $scope.MySelectionClass();
        $scope.session.RegisterSelectionObserver($scope.selectionObserver);
    }
}
```

**Class Definition:**

```
$scope.MySelectionClass = Module.SelectionEvents.extend("SelectionEvents", {
        __construct: function() {
            this.__parent.__construct.call(this);
            this.SetEventsFilter(Module.EVENTS_PICKS | Module.EVENTS_SELECTION);
        },

        OnSelectionBegin: function () {
            if ($scope.webglSettings.selectionLogging === 'YES') {
                console.log("OnSelectionBegin");
            }
        },
     });
```

**My Adoption:**
I've tried to create a class with its constructor and pass it to observer registration, with an error.

**My Custom class:**

```
export class ExtSelectionEvents{
    constructor(){
    }

    OnSelectionBegin(){
        console.log('OnSelectionBegin');
    }
}
```

**My Registering:**

```
const extSelectionEventsInstance = new ExtSelectionEvents();
session.RegisterSelectionObserver(extSelectionEventsInstance);
```

**Error:**

> zone.js:703 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot pass "[object Object]"
>   as a SelectionEvents* ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   BindingError {name: "BindingError", message: "Cannot pass "[object
>   Object]" as a SelectionEvents*", stack: "BindingError: Cannot pass
>   "[object Object]" as a S…erences
>   (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:181:13)"}message: "Cannot pass
>   "[object Object]" as a SelectionEvents*"name: "BindingError"stack:
>   "BindingError: Cannot pass "[object Object]" as a SelectionEvents*↵
>   at BindingError.
>   (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:117337)↵
>   **at new BindingError (eval at createNamedFunction (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:116224),
>   :4:34)↵    at throwBindingError
>   (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:118918)↵    at
>   RegisteredPointer.nonConstNoSmartPtrRawPointerToWireType [as
>   toWireType]**
>   (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:134368)↵    at
>   Session$RegisterSelectionObserver [as RegisterSelectionObserver] (eval
>   at new_
>   (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:142970),
>   :8:26)↵    at
>   OverviewComponent.push../src/app/views/mechportal/overview/overview.component.ts.OverviewComponent.callback
>   (http://localhost:4200/views-mechportal-overview-overview-module.js:18109:17)↵
>   at http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:18:31↵    at
>   http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:182:17↵    at _loadPreferences
>   (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:304:9)↵    at Object.LoadPreferences
>   (http://localhost:4200/scripts.js:181:13)"**proto**: Error
>   BindingError: Cannot pass "[object Object]" as a SelectionEvents*
>       at BindingError. (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:117337)
>       at new BindingError (eval at createNamedFunction (http://localhost:4200/assets/js/libthingview_wasm.js:1:116224),
>   :4:34)

**Summary:**

The library is expecting an annonymous function for OnSelectionBegin, because it is creating a named function of it.

What is happening in MySelectionClass and how can I translate the AngularJS Class definition with its annonymous function to work with Angular 8 / the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class SelectionEvents was the missing peace.

After the global delcaration of Module (declare var Module: any) I finally could extend the SelectionEvents class and implement my methods.

The only difference between the implementations of Angular and AngularJS was the different scopes. In AngularJS it was bound to the scope of the controller and now it is in global scope.

```
   const MyEventsClass = Module.SelectionEvents.extend("SelectionEvents", {

  __construct: function () {
    this.__parent.__construct.call(this);
    this.SetEventsFilter(Module.EVENTS_PICKS | Module.EVENTS_SELECTION);
  },

  OnSelectionBegin: function () {
      console.log("OnSelectionBegin");
      console.dir(this);
  }
});

session.RegisterSelectionObserver(new MyEventsClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that, but you should cope with the JS class :

```
export class ExtSelectionEvents extends SelectionEvents{
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    OnSelectionBegin(){
        console.log('OnSelectionBegin');
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to extend Selection Events I got a ReferenceError: SelectionEvents is not defined.

Comment: @BenjaminSteiner well you should find where it comes from, since in AJS, they extend from it.

Comment: Thanks for your hint with the SelectionEvents Extension. Got it working with the extension of SelectionEvents. This class was only available in global scope. So I declared it as Module and could init the class like this:

    const MyEventsClass = Module.SelectionEvents.extend("SelectionEvents", {

      __construct: function () {
        this.__parent.__construct.call(this);
        this.SetEventsFilter(Module.EVENTS_PICKS | Module.EVENTS_SELECTION);
      },

      OnSelectionBegin: function () {
          console.log("OnSelectionBegin");
      }
    });

Comment: Well no problem, glad I could help !